# Mean Value theorem question possibly wrong

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on the set of real numbers $R$. Suppose that $f(1)=4$ and $f(2)=2$.

Show that the equation $f(x) -2x=0$ has real solution on the interval $(1,2)$

Shouldn't the question be $f(x)+2x=0$ since then $f'(x)=-2$ holds from MVT.

Comment: Hint: You should try to apply intermediate value theorem on $h(x)=f(x)-2x$ in the interval $(1,2)$. The question is correct.

Comment: Check $f(x)-2x=0$ at value of $x=1$ and $x=2$ you will find that value of $f(x)-2x=0$ is negative at $x=2$ and positive at $x=1$ and the function is continuious, so function $f(x)-2x$ will cross the $x$ axis at least one time. So there is a value of $x$ where $y$ is zero i.e $f(x)-2x=0$ is zero , that value of $x$ is will be root .

Comment: This is not a question about the Mean Value Theorem, but the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't wrong.

Consider $g(x) = f(x) -2x$
$$ g(1) = f(1)-2 = 4-2=2$$
$$ g(2) = f(2)-4=2-4=-2$$
$$g(1) \cdot g(2) < 0$$
So there exists a solution to $g(x)$ in $(1,2)$ as $g(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you my approach was incorrect. Much appreciated!